# ‘There is a double yolk in the egg.’

Tags: modifiers

> ‘There is a double yolk in the egg.’

If one of two yolks is red, should I say ‘part of a double yolk’ is red or ‘one of a double yolk’ is red? (Part of a double helix is damaged, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, I would only use "Part of the **double** [x]..." if the thing I was describing affected a portion of *each element* of [x].

For example, there could be a double rainbow, but one sector of the double rainbow could be invisible due to shadows or something. Then I could say: *Part of the double rainbow is not visible.*

Or there could be a double helix (for example two intertwining staircases), and a segment *of both* has been painted red. Then I could say: *Part of the double helix is red.*

But if *only one* of the helices was painted red, I would say that instead: *One of the two helices is red.*

So in your case, **no**, I would not describe a single yolk as being red. I would say *One of the two yolks is red.*

Answer (score 1):

No need to overthink this.

> One of the yolks is red.

Don't say "part of the double yolk" or "one of the double yolk".

Don't worry about the fact that the egg has a double yolk, so it has two yolks.  Similarly DNA has a double helix, which means it is made of two helices; a double whisky has two shots of whisky... etc.